# Sorting questions by order in a survey system

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am building a survey system for a professor at my university using PDO/MySQL and PHP. I have one table for questions, and that table has a multitude of information in it, including `question_id`, `question`, `enabled`, and `order`. When a survey is created, all `question_id`s where `enabled = 1` are imploded into a string and stored in a separate `survey` table. In the future when questions are edited, the system will simply disable the old question and add the new version to the end of the table and update everything with the proper value for `order`, thus allowing old surveys to still be viewed in their original state.

I am struggling to figure out how to best handle the ordering aspect of this. I can easily display the output data if I have a string stored in the database for the `question_id`s (for example, my string would be `2,3,5,6,9,4,1`)--I could use `explode()` and then iterate through the default 0-index of that array, calling each question in turn. How can I store the values in the proper order?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

by imploding into a string you are denormalising your data.  i'd advise against it and especially in this instance.  use a separate table to manage the links between questions and surveys.

i've found this a bit strange because i havent understood exactly what you are trying to do.  I think you are creating a single online survey - 1 survey with a single purpose rather than a tool for creating lots of unrelated surveys.  so if my assumption is correct i would make some more tables

```
TABLE Surveys (
SurveyId INT UNSIGNED PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
SurveyTitle VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
SurveyDescription TEXT,
Owner VARCHAR(100),
BLAH BLAH BLAH
);

TABLE Questions (
QuestionId INT UNSIGNED PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
Version INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
Question TEXT,
OrderNumber INT UNSIGNED,
Enabled ENUM('Yes', 'No') DEFAULT 'Yes'
);

TABLE SurveyQuestions (
SQId INT UNSIGNED PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
SurveyId INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
QuestionId INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
Version INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL
);

TABLE QuestionHistory (
QuestionId INT UNSIGNED,  // notice we dont have a primary key i would probably do a composite key on QuestionId and Version
Version INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
Question TEXT,
OrderNumber INT UNSIGNED,
Enabled ENUM('Yes', 'No') DEFAULT 'Yes',
DateSuperceded DATETIME
);
```

you would also need an table for surveyees and their responses, the response should probably link to the SurveyQuestions table.  It also better to use an auto id on the question history table - but that depends on what exactly you want to do.

this is a much longer answer than i wanted to post.  apologies if i've confused the issue more than clarified.  If you want to post a more detailed spec of what you're trying to create then I can give better advice.

Comment: I should have clarified that I do have additional tables in my system, not just the two I mentioned. I'm working with someone who really knows what he's doing. I have an `answers` table (id, question_id, survey_id, value), `questions` (all data related to each question), `surveys` (contains information for each survey that has been started), and `users` (all user-related information). I am creating a system to facilitate just one survey and for this one survey to be easily editable by someone who has no idea what they're doing. My way seemed like the simplest way to manage a question...

Comment: ..list without creating an entirely separate table for a list of questions--just parse the question ids as a string, then pull that string and loop through it to display each question. Incredibly simple to do. Does it need to be more difficult than that? (Not saying you're wrong, just explaining why I used this approach. I'm still brand new to PHP.)

Comment: mysql is a relational database - its good at what it does and very fast.  so use it.  use the relations.  or go real simple and dump the db all together and store stuff in concatenated strings in a text file.  your way isnt exactly wrong just half way there.  the relational db solves problems like what happens when i update a question or change the order etc.  I would seriously read up on relational dbs.  get your db structure right and the php becomes much easier.

Comment: I wasn't even aware that the concept of relational databases existed, and was coding around that. This will take a heck of a lot more research, and I feel like most of my work thus far is now for nothing. Thank you, I appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

Just get rid of `"all question_ids are imploded into a string and stored in a separate survey table"` part, as it's useless and wrong.

So, every time you need your question ids in order - just select them from questions table, ordering by `order` field.

Do not complicate things without a reason. You'll make your life a lot easier.
A real reason I mean, not imaginable one.
When it comes to database design, such a rule can be formulated in a form of a law: [Always keep your database in a Normal form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization)

I hope for the results you have another table, consists of `user id`, `question id` and `an answer`.

Comment: Wouldn't my method be easier though? I have a separate table that stores all of the information for each survey, with columns for the username, question list, date started, date ended, and whether completed or not. I have to store the information *somewhere* as to what questions the person had when they started the form, so wouldn't ordering this question list be the most sensible option? Then I just need to call the list of question IDs (that's all it is, just a list of numbers) and loop through to display each question's data.